# Why the child thread block in my code?

Tags: pthreads, mutex

I was trying to test the pthread by using mutex:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int global = 0;
void thread_set();
void thread_read();



int main(void){
  pthread_t thread1, thread2;
  int re_value1, re_value2;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    re_value1 = pthread_create(&thread1,NULL, (void*)&thread_set,NULL);
    re_value2 = pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,(void*)&thread_read,NULL);
  }

  pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
  pthread_join(thread2,NULL);
  /* sleep(2); */ // without it the 5 iteration couldn't finish
  printf("exsiting\n");
  exit(0);
}

void thread_set(){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
  printf("Setting data\t");
  global = rand();
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
}
void thread_read(){
  int data;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
  data = global;
  printf("the value is: %d\n",data);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
}
```

without the `sleep()`, the code won't finish the 5 iteration:

Setting data    the value is: 1804289383
the value is: 1804289383
Setting data    the value is: 846930886
exsiting

Setting data    the value is: 1804289383
Setting data    the value is: 846930886
the value is: 846930886
exsiting

It works only add the sleep() to the main thread, I think it should work without the `sleep()`, because the join() function wait for each child thread terminate

Any one can tell me why is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of mutex objects looks fine, but this loop

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     re_value1 = pthread_create(&thread1,NULL, (void*)&thread_set,NULL);
     re_value2 = pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,(void*)&thread_read,NULL);
}
```

is asking for trouble as you are reusing the same thread instances `thread1` and `thread2` for each iteration of your loop. Internally this must be causing problems although I do not know exactly how it would manifest itself.  You should really use a separate instance of thread object per thread you want to ensure reliable running. I do not know what would happen if you called `pthread_create` using an instance of a thread object that is already running but I suspect it is not a wise thing to do. I would suspect that at best it will block until the thread function has exited.

Also you are not cheking the return values from `pthread_create()` either which might be a good idea. In summary I would use a separate instance of thread objects, or add the `pthread_join` calls to the inside of your loop so that you are certain that the threads are finished running before the next call to `pthread_create()`.

Finally the function signature for functions passed to `pthread_create()` are of the type

```
 void* thread_function(void*);
```

and not

```
 void thead_function()
```

like you have in your code.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, I'm not read the part where explain the structure of `(void *)`, is that type casting or a pointer point to NULL?

Comment: @yozloy I think that the main problem is with your loop where you create threads. You should address the problem with the thread functions though. When I started using pthreads I used this resource which might be useful to you http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

Comment: so `void* thread_function(void*)` it takes void pointer and also return void pointer, am I right?

Comment: yes but you can pass NULL and return NULL if you do not want to use them

Comment: After I change`(void*)&thread_set` to thread_set and void thread_set() to void* thread_set() as you suggest, it generate error

Comment: you shouldnt have to explicitly cast your function to a (void*). Did you read that tutorial link I posted? http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15077/discussion-between-yozloy-and-mathematician1975)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating 10 threads (5 iterations of two threads each), but only joining the last two you create (as mathematician1975 notes, you're re-using the thread handle variables, so the values from the last iteration are the only ones you have available to join on). Without the `sleep()`, it's quite possible that the scheduler has not started executing the first 8 threads before you hit `exit()`, which automatically terminates all threads, whether they have had a chance to run yet or not.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the I only join the last two. But there are only two `pthread_t` `thread1` and `thread2` which I pass to pthread_create, I don't understand what's other 8 thread's pthread_t

Comment: The other 8 threads get stored successively in `thread1` and `thread2`, but those are then overwritten on the next iteration of the loop, and so they are lost. Perhaps you meant to put the `pthread_join()`s inside the loop as well?

Comment: interestingly, after I put `pthread_join()` inside the loop, there only 4 output in totally each time, and `existing` right after the 5th `Setting data`